# building glibc for old kernel

Tags: debian, kernel, glibc, configure

[image: configure command args]

I configured build with this command and built it using make

Now I'm trying to create deb package with this settings
[image: error while creating deb package]
but i failed with this error
FATAL : kernel too old
how can i do it?

Comment: Try to use a PC.

Comment: it will work, but my purpose is to install it on my old galaxy s(i installed debian jessie on it using chroot) will it able to install on it? @Biswapriyo